# Evitar el salto de línea al leer con fgets

Tags: fgets

Porque cuando uso fgets(cadena,5,stdin) , y yo inserto solo dos caracteres AB
el comando strlen(cadena)  me retorna el valor de 3

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main() {
  char nombre[20]="";
  printf("Ingresa Nombre: ");  
  fgets(nombre,5,stdin);
  printf("Cadena es : %s\n",nombre);
  printf("Longitud es : %d\n",strlen(nombre));

  printf("nombre[0]= %c\n",nombre[0]);
  printf("nombre[1]= %c\n",nombre[1]);
  printf("nombre[2]= %c\n",nombre[2]);
  printf("nombre[3]= %c\n",nombre[3]);
  printf("nombre[4]= %c\n",nombre[4]);

  return 0;
}
```

Al ejecutarlo tenemos

```
Ingresa Nombre: AB
Cadena es : AB

Longitud es : 3
nombre[0]= A
nombre[1]= B
nombre[2]=

nombre[3]=
nombre[4]=
```

Obs Veo un ERROR Porque strlen(cadena) me retorna 3 , si yo ingrese : AB
parece que fgets rellena con un ENTER  .
Yo  necesito que strlen(cadena) me retorne el valor correcto osea 2
Como debo hacer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No hay ningún error, según [su documentación](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3p.html):

> #### SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
>    #include <stdio.h>
>    char *fgets(char *restrict s, int n, FILE *restrict stream);<br>
> ```
>
> #### DESCRIPTION
>
> The fgets() function shall read bytes from stream into the array pointed to by s, until n−1 bytes are read, or a  is read and transferred to s, or an end-of-file condition is encountered. The string is then terminated with a null byte.

En traducción *muy mucho* libre por mi parte:

> La función lee datos desde el *stream* de entrada y los coloca en el *array* indicado, hasta el tamaño `n - 1`, o si se lee un nueva-línea (que es transferida al *array*), o se produce un fin-de-archivo.
>   
>   Al final de los datos leídos, se coloca un *byte* `0`.

Vemos que la función hace exactamente lo que se supone debe de hacer

> Yo necesito que strlen( cadena ) me retorne el valor correcto

Sencillo:

```
fgets( nombre, 5, stdin );
if( nombre[strlen( nombre ) - 1] == '\n' ) {
  nombre[strlen( nombre ) - 1] = 0;
}
```

Simplemente, comprobamos si la cadena tiene un salto de línea al final y, de ser así, lo reemplazamos por un fín-de-cadena ( un `0` ).